# How to fit the output of Python code in pdf while using R markdown?

Tags: python, pdf, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am trying to Knit an R Markdown file to PDF. I have a few Python code chunks in that, output of one of which is not fitting the page.
I have also read about setting the width of R chunks, but sadly those functions do not work when `{python…………}` is used.
My code:

```
Marks = [23,19,14,10,23,34,15,19,24,19,2,20,30]

for Score in Marks : 
    if Score > 15 : 
        print(Score, "-", "The candidate has passed.")
    else :
        print(Score, "-", "The candidate has failed.")
 
OpenDay = ["The Score is" + " " + str(Score) + " " + "and The candidate has passed." if Score > 15 in Marks 
else "The Score is" + " " + str(Score) + " " + "and The candidate has failed." for Score in Marks]

print(OpenDay)
```

Please help! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMuW5.jpg)

Comment: Can't you simply spread the content of the brackets in OpenDay = [...] over multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People often face the same problem when writing code, since it should fit neatly within the window. You could format the `OpenDay` assignment like this:

```
OpenDay = [
    (
        "The Score is " + str(Score) 
        + " and The candidate has passed."
    ) if Score > 15 else (
        "The Score is " + str(Score) 
        + " and The candidate has failed."
    )
    for Score in Marks
]
```

This has a couple of simplifications and code fixes but I would probably simplify it further:

```
OpenDay = [
    "The score is {} and the candidate has {}."
    .format(Score, "passed" if Score > 15 else "failed")
    for Score in Marks
]
```

Comment: Yes, the code has fit the page, but not its output. 
The output still breaks through the right border.

Comment: I can't tell how you are getting the output into your document. But if you are just copying text from a window, you could try putting in line breaks after each string. Or you could try using the `pprint` function from the `pprint` module instead of the regular `print`.

Comment: @HrishikeshHardikar Please mark the question as answered.